# RxJS catchError to handle caught$ to retry 2 times

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, rxjs

Here I need to `caught$` to retry 2 times and after that show the error message and `throwError(err)`. Please let me know how to do that here.

```
this.locationChanged$ = this.locationsService
      .getLocationById()
      .pipe(
        catchError((err,caught$) => {
          //how to retry 2 times here

          // after that this workflow
          console.log(err);
          return throwError(err);
        }),
        retry(2),
        finalize(() => {
         //code
        })
      );
```

When I do like so above it logs the `console.log(err);` also `3 times`. So how can I avoid that? i.e. I need to do that only once.

Comment: Just add `retry` operator?

Comment: @Neistow Can I have a code sample here?

Comment: [Official docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/retry), [learnrxjs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/retry)

Comment: @Neistow Yes, how to apply that to this use case? Can I have a sample code from you?

Comment: The operators flow is important. Move the `retry(2)` above the `catchError` opeartor. Currently, you are retrying the source request only after the `catchError` block, so it gets triggered for each `retry` attempt.

Comment: @ruth Oh... I didn't know about it. Please put that as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, the operator order affects the behaviour of the chain. Each operator modifies the observable and returns the modified observable to the next opeartor.

For the `retry(2)` to be triggered before the `catchError` opeartor, it must be above the `catchError` operator.

Try the following

```js
this.locationChanged$ = this.locationsService
  .getLocationById()
  .pipe(
    retry(2),                       // <-- before `catchError`
    catchError((err,caught$) => {
      console.log(err);
      return throwError(err);
    }),
    finalize(() => {
      //code
    })
  );
```